# SvelteKit Hook Prevents Endpoint Request

Tags: javascript, server-side-rendering, svelte, sveltekit

Trying out SvelteKit and I'm having a hard time with hooks. The docs don't really seem to explain it all too well. My current understanding of hooks is that they basically allow you to interact with requests made to your server before they get to their destination? (I'm open to a better explanation - specifically the `handle` hook).
My current issue is I made an endpoint called `login`. As the name suggests, it allows users to sign into my application by generating a token and storing it as a cookie on their client. This works until I add hooks. After reading the hooks description, I figured the `handle` hook is perfect for what I want to do - validate the token on each request - if invalid, reroute the user to the login screen, if valid, allow the request to continue uninterrupted.

```js
export const handle: Handle = async ({ event, resolve }) => {

    const isLogin = event.url.pathname.startsWith('/login')

    const cookies = cookie.parse(event.request.headers.get('cookie') || '');
    const token = cookies['token']

    if (!token) {
        
        if (!isLogin) {
            
            return Response.redirect(`${event.url.origin}/login`)
        }
        return await resolve(event)
    } else {
        
        try {
            
            await verifyToken(token)

            if (isLogin) {
                
                return Response.redirect(`${event.url.origin}/about`)
            }
        } catch (err) {
            return Response.redirect(`${event.url.origin}/login`)
        }
    }

    return await resolve(event)

};
```

This does not work as expected. When I initiate the request to the `api/login` endpoint, the request does not seem to make it there. I have `console.log`s all over the endpoint but no messages were outputted to the terminal & when I check the application storage, no new cookie was added.

What am I missing about hooks?
Why is it not passing the request off to the endpoint?

Any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: You are using a `/login` route and mentioning a `api/login` endpoint, are you sure your paths are correct ? I tried locally to redirect this way and it works (both hitting the correct page and correct endpoint).

Comment: I am calling the correct endpoint. When I remove the rerouting logic from the handle hook, the endpoint gets hit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `handle` hook runs for *every* request—including endpoints.

When you fetch `/api/login` without a token, your hook will redirect the request to `/login` since `isLogin === false`. You need to allow through *every* route that should be accessible without a login, for example:

```js
const isLogin = /^\/(api\/)?login$/.test(event.url.pathname)
```

Comment: I did eventually figure this out but thanks for getting back to me with a response.

Comment: In those cases, you're free to close or answer your own question here in SO.